# Setting the selected attribute on a select list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have the following HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

I have the string "B" so I want to set the `selected` attribute on it so it will be:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option>A</option>
    <option selected="selected">B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

How would I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying your HTML a little to include the `value` attribute of the options, you can significantly reduce the code necessary to do this:

```
<option>B</option>
```

to

```
<option value="B">B</option>
```

This will be helpful when you want to do something like:

```
<option value="IL">Illinois</option>
```

With that, the follow jQuery will make the change:

```
$("select option[value='B']").attr("selected","selected");
```

If you decide *not* to include the use of the `value` attribute, you will be required to cycle through each option, and manually check its value:

```
$("select option").each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == "B")
    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
});
```

Comment: After adding the `value` attributes, the selection can also be done like this: `$("#dropdown").val("B");`

Comment: Hi *@Jonathan Sampson*: Nice solution. All other things recommend setting .val() but that just didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Setting `.val()` WILL NOT call `.change()` event binded to your `<select>`. Just saying...

Comment: how does one select the dropdown id? $("select option") << this is generic

Comment: If you want to fire the `.change()` event binded to your select you can use `$(this).change()`

Comment: @madtyn $.fn.prop didn't get added until 2011. This answer predates that by a few years. Additionally, though not my intention, by changing the attribute you can enable greater control over styling via attribute selectors.

Comment: `.val()` and `.prop()` don't change/set the attribute. But this behavior is required in some cases and is only done with `.attr()` http://jsfiddle.net/6sebLnrz/

Comment: And how can I remove the old `selected` attribute ?

Comment: @stack See `removeAttr`.

Comment: It's the year 2021 and this is the answer helped me. God bless you sir

Answer (score 15):

```
<select id="cars">
<option value='volvo'>volvo</option>
<option value='bmw'>bmw</option>
<option value='fiat'>fiat</option>
</select>

var make = "fiat";

$("#cars option[value='" + make + "']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are using JQuery, since the 1.6 you have to use the .prop() method :

```
$('select option:nth(1)').prop("selected","selected");
```

Comment: This solution is best. `.attr()` doesn't allow multiple changes. `.prop()` does.

Answer (score 3):

I'd iterate through the options, comparing the text to what I want to be selected, then set the selected attribute on that option.  Once you find the correct one, terminate the iteration (unless you have a multiselect).

```
 $('#dropdown').find('option').each( function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.text() == 'B') {
         $this.attr('selected','selected');
         return false;
      }
 });
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use .find() rather than $('#dropdown option')? More efficient? The "var $this" stuff also looks wrong to me ...

Comment: I think the difference is mainly stylistic.  Under the hood I would expect them to operate basically the same way.  Get a collection, filter it.  I've started using $this as a way to hold a reference to the jQuery object.  I've also seen self (or $self), but I think that's less clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the .selectedIndex strategy of danielrmt, but determine the index based on the text within the option tags like this:

```
$('#dropdown')[0].selectedIndex = $('#dropdown option').toArray().map(jQuery.text).indexOf('B');
```

This works on the original HTML without using value attributes.

Answer (score 2):

## This can be a solution

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure DOM. See http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

```
document.getElementById('dropdown').selectedIndex = 1;
```

but jQuery can help:

```
$('#dropdown').selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: This presumes that you know which element has the desired value.  That's not always the case when the list is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
var select = function(dropdown, selectedValue) {
    var options = $(dropdown).find("option");
    var matches = $.grep(options,
        function(n) { return $(n).text() == selectedValue; });
    $(matches).attr("selected", "selected");
};
```

Example:

```
select("#dropdown", "B");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#select_id option:eq(0)').prop('selected', 'selected');
```

its good

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of...

```
$('select option:nth(1)').attr("selected","selected");
```