# setting the value of a select form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

so apparently you have the following

```
<select>
    <option value="0">One</option>
    <option value="1">Two</option>
</select>

$('select').val('1'); // selects "Two"
$('select').val('Two'); // also selects "Two"
```

but what if you have

```
   <select>
        <option value="0">1</option>
        <option value="1">0</option>
    </select>
```

And I want to set the value...of the form...how can I tell jquery to specifically use the value field or specifically the text in between the option tag...

Comment: Hint: you don't set the value, you set the selectedIndex.

Comment: It doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9ySD/.

Comment: @pimvdb - Actually this seems to work if you remove the values from the option elements. jQuery's .val() page actually uses an example like this, although I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: @j08691: You're correct. Though the OP's confusion doesn't apply in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the `option` based on the value (with the attribute selector) and set the selected attribute like this:

```
var value = "1"; // Set the value that you want to select
$("select option[value=" + value + "]")​​.attr("selected","selected")​​;​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VU9BC/

Answer (score 3):

```
​$('select').find('option[value="1"]')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.attr('selected', true );
```

Comment: It should be `.attr('selected', 'selected')`

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it's correct.  The correct value for the selected attribute for a selected element is "selected" and not "true".

Comment: Yup, but jquery sets it for you, inspect the DOM and notice it sets 'selected' = 'selected'. So this IS correct. Just because you disagree doesn't mean the other person is wrong. And by the way this is pretty standard in jquery, just like `attr.('checked', true)`. You not knowing about it doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: I_C, kindly read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311287/jquery-setting-the-selected-attribute-on-a-select-list  I also encourage you to Google the proper way to assign the selected attribute to an option element.

Comment: I apologize Senor, i understand what you're getting at. But why does setting `.attr('checked', true)` work then, for checkboxes ? And also it's suggested on the jQuery page and many other stackoverflow pages. Even thought everyone knows it's supposed to be `.attr('checked', 'checked')` ?

Comment: Here's what jquery does. `if ( value === false ) {
   // Remove boolean attributes when set to false
   jQuery.removeAttr( elem, name );
  } else {
   // value is true since we know at this point it's type boolean and not false
   // Set boolean attributes to the same name and set the DOM property
   propName = jQuery.propFix[ name ] || name;
   if ( propName in elem ) {
    // Only set the IDL specifically if it already exists on the element
    elem[ propName ] = true;
   }

   elem.setAttribute( name, name.toLowerCase() );
  }`

Comment: As you can see it explicitly checks for booleans and if it's false then it removes the attribute. This is no mistake. It's a shorthand. So you don't have to do `removeAttr` when you don't want the property there anymore, you just set it to false.

Comment: See for yourself https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L506 and tell me why they do that then ?

Answer (score 0):

Just select the option based on the value (with the attribute selector) and set the selected attribute like this Simply no Headace :)

**By Value**

```
$( "select" ).change( displayVals );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/haroonmind/quemz47o/1/