# How you can I put selected = "selected" dynamic?Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyMKzW)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<select name="card_type" id="card_type" class="card-sel com-c select-full">
        <option value="visa">Visa</option>
        <option value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
        <option value="discovery">Discovery</option>
        <option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
</select>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var stateSelectValue = "Mastercard"; //this value in my site returns a dynamic type of card
    console.log("primul log" + stateSelectValue);

    if(stateSelectValue)
    {
     console.log("al doilea log" + stateSelectValue);  $("#card_type").val(stateSelectValue).attr("selected","selected").trigger("change");
        console.log("al treilea log" + stateSelectValue);
    }
        $( ".com-c" ).change(function() {
            var data= $(this).val();
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

Perhaps the example understand what they want to do.

Basically when they are receiving a value in the variable `stateSelectValue`  to look if there is value in that list and make selected.

For example IF:

```
 var stateSelectValue = "Mastercard";
```

then

```
<option value="mastercard" selected="selected">Mastercard</option>
```

and so on...

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$("#card_type").val(stateSelectValue)` This should be enough. You dont have to set `selected` attribute and fire change event.

Comment: in my example, if you look empty ... do not display the value of the first

Comment: @abshishekkanoijia can you edit my example please?I tried to do that but not working

Answer (score 0):

First as I have already commented, you do not need to set attribute `selected` and trigger `change` function.

```
$("#card_type").val(stateSelectValue)
```

This should be enough.

Second, if you do this change, still it will not work. W
**Why?:**

Variable value:

```
var stateSelectValue = "Mastercard";
```

is not equal to `value` of option

```
<option value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
```

**[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/rajesh_dixit/pen/xZLRjy)**

Answer (score 0):

You were all good just one typo mistake, your selected value was in capital i.e "Mastercard" where as in option value it was "mastercard". But in simple way doing below was enough without trigger change event.

```js
 var stateSelectValue = "mastercard";
  
  
    $("#card_type").val(stateSelectValue)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="card_type" id="card_type" class="card-sel com-c select-full">
        <option value="visa">Visa</option>
        <option value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
        <option value="discovery">Discovery</option>
        <option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question already asked some . please refers the below link:

[JQuery setting the selected attribute on a select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311287/jquery-setting-the-selected-attribute-on-a-select-list)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#card_type').val("mastercard");    // Select by value
    text1 = "Maestro";
    $("#card_type option:contains(" + text1 + ")").attr('selected', 'selected'); // select by text
});
```