# How the rails select box selected option is giving from coffee file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

In a js.coffee file after an ajax success, i need to put values to a select box with selected a particular name.

**_form.html,erb** :

```
<%= f.select(:user_id, Item.find(session[:login_users_item_id]).try(:users).order_by_fullname.collect {|u| [ u.full_name, u.id ] }, selected: current_user.id)%>
```

**items.js.coffee**:

```
$.ajax '/users.json',   
type: 'GET', data: {"from_prod_bu" : selecteditemId},
success: (data) ->
  userSelectBox = $('#prod_user_id')
  userSelectBox.html('')
  if data.length == 0
    userSelectBox.append($('<option>').text('').attr('value', ''))
  else
    $.each data, (index,el) ->
      userSelectBox.append($('<option>').text(el.firstname+' '+el.lastname).attr('value', el.id))
```

Now, the user fullname is listing in the select box, but how can i give the selected option for displaying a particular username .

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear - what specific option do you want to be preselected? If that option is already known within your JS code, see the answer below. If the selected user's id is expected to be passed via AJAX, the below code can be easily modified depending on how it is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected option is set [by using the `selected` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option).

Suppose that the `id` of the user to be selected is stored in the `selectedUserId` variable within your JavaScript - then the following code should work:

```
success: (data) ->
  userSelectBox = $('#prod_user_id')
  userSelectBox.html('')
  if data.length == 0
    userSelectBox.append($('<option>').text('').attr('value', ''))
  else
    $.each data, (index, el) ->
      option = $('<option>')
        .text(el.firstname + ' ' + el.lastname)
        .attr('value', el.id)
      if el.id == selectedUserId
         option.attr 'selected', 'selected'
      userSelectBox.append option
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311287/jquery-setting-the-selected-attribute-on-a-select-list) for more details on setting the `selected` attribute with jQuery.