# uncalled javascript function start during other function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a fiunction that set value to form field from Object and during execution another uncalled function start and I do not why....

```
function loadRecord(i) {// Function for display records which are retrived from database.
    var item = dataset.item(i);
    $("#data_id").val((item['id']).toString());
    $("#source").val((item['source']).toString());
    $("#s_date").val((item['s_date']).toString());
    $("#lat").val((item['lat']).toString());
    $("#lon").val((item['lon']).toString());
    $("#acc").val((item['acc']).toString());
    $("#image").attr("src", item['photo']);
    $("#photo").val((item['photo']).toString());
    $("#exif").val((item['exif']).toString());
>>>>$("#wateres").val((item['wateres']).toString()).change(); //the other function sart here!
    $("#top").val((item['top']).toString()).change();
    $("#pump").val((item['pump']).toString()).change();
    ..... the function continue normally
```

The form fields are identified by $("input_id") the  only difference in the row that cause the unwanted behaviour is that is the first select of the form. But if I comment this row everything work well and the next row (is a select to)

Comment: The other function is probably called by a click event handler, which could be bound by HTML `onchange` attribute, or a jQuery `$("#top").change(...)` call, or many other variants of how events can be listened to. Without more information we cannot know....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you define some event on that item?

Like

```
$("#wateres").on("change", function(e){});
```

Because when you apply `change()` it Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

From docs  https://api.jquery.com/change/

So check your code for that listener.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I've that on my form `<select id="wateres" onchange="wrForm(this.value)">`

Comment: So you have your answer... When you run .change() it triggers onchange="wrForm(this.value)" and it runs that function. Glad that it help you.

Comment: Maybe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value .. Just use yourID val your value.

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311287/jquery-setting-the-selected-attribute-on-a-select-list